# Wix Toolset: How to reference custom wix extension in wix project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix3.10, wix-extension

I have created a test WIX extension project following the [manual](http://snhconsultingltd.com/2013/12/14/extending-wix-by-creating-a-custom-wix-extension/).
When I am trying to use this extension in the Wix Setup project, Visual Studio is not able to find a namespace of just linked wix extension dll.

Even more, if I just copy the extension namespace in the project's namespaces, Visual Studio does not recognize it and does not provide intellisense to use an element from the Wix extension.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:awesome="http://www.example.com/AwesomeSchema">
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just manually copied the xsd schema into %VisualStudioInstallFolder%\Xml\Schemas.